# Event Change in IE not working when pressing Enter Button

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I want to execute a function in change of an input[type=text], this works fine in all Browsers except in IE.

This is an exemple :

```
$('input.switch').change(function(){
    alert('ok now');    
});
```

the text input looks like that :
`<input class="switch" type="text" value="50000" />`

Don't forget that i have many inputs with different classes !

Do you have in solutions for this ?

Comment: What happens in IE? Any error? Have you tried `if($(this).prop('checked'))`?

Comment: In IE, the event is executed when the input has losed the focus !! :\

Comment: That's the case for text inputs in all browsers... your code does not seem to refer to a text input though.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to activate an event when pressing Enter then register this event:

```
$('input.switch:first').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode==13) { //Enter keycode
        //Do you stuff
    }
});
```

Enter doesn't activate change maybe because the text input doesn't lose focus.

Good luck!

Update:
The latest version of jQuery allows you to get the focused element using: `$('*:focus')`. I believe you should add script that will support IE. For each keydown, if the key is Enter, get the focused input, blur it and trigger change:

```
$('body').keydown(function() {
    if (e.keyCode==13) { //Enter keycode
        $('input:focus').blur().change(); //The blur is to prevent change happen again
    }
});
```

I am not sure you can force IE to trigger change when Enter pressed in different way.

Hope this helps this time.

Comment: Yes, i know this but i want to use change event, the problem is juste in IE :'(.

Comment: just a quick comment, the keydown function needs to have "e" in there as well: $('body').keydown(function(e) {

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more targeted polyfill for IE:

```
var isIE = !!document.documentMode;
if (isIE) {

    $("body").on("keydown", "input[type='text']", function (e) {

        // Ensure 'change' event is fired on enter in IE
        if ((e.keyCode || e.which) === 13) {
            $(this).blur();
        }
    });
}
```